# Error on grails changing the javascript file

Tags: javascript, grails

I'm working on a web project using Grails 2.3.7.

Every time I change any Javascript file and refresh the page, I've get direct to a blank page with the following message:
"Resources are being processed, please wait..."

After some research, I discover that have something to do with the "DevModeSanityFilter.groovy".

Can anyone give a help so a can change the JS file and see the changes without this message and without restarting the server?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the abandoned and deprecated `resources` plugin from your `BuildConfig.groovy` and use the [asset-pipeline](http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline) plugin instead. asset-pipeline uses a much better approach to resource handling and is actively developed.

Comment: This one: runtime ":resources:1.2.7"?

Comment: Yes, replace that with `compile ':asset-pipeline:2.11.0'` and check out the docs at http://asset-pipeline.com/manual/index.html for usage info

Comment: I've got this error log:

Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56792', transport: 'socket'
|Loading Grails 2.3.7
|Configuring classpath
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:zip:2.11.0

Comment: Try adding `grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"` in BuildConfig.groovy if it's not there, and consider upgrading to a version of Grails that's a few years more recent :)